# MonoDroid Bluetooth

Tags: c#, android, bluetooth, xamarin.android

I have been working with Monodroid for a few days and still can't figure out how to send a command through Bluetooth.

This is my scenario: I have a Tablet/Cellphone working with Android 2.1+ and need to send and receive data to a Bluetooth printer (in bytes).

What i managed so far:

```
using Android.Bluetooth; // library necessary

BluetoothAdapter bth = BluetoothAdapter.DefaultAdapter;
if (!bth.IsEnabled)
    bth.Enable();

ICollection<BluetoothDevice> bthD = bth.BondedDevices;

foreach (BluetoothDevice d in bthD)
{
    if (d.Name == "DPP-350")
    {
        Java.Util.UUID UUID = Java.Util.UUID.FromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
        // Get the BLuetoothDevice object
        BluetoothSocket s = d.CreateRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID);

        s.Connect();

        // Try to send command
        ...

        s.Close()
    }
}
```

The program asks for the pairing info, with is done correctly. 
I have tried many ways to send the command:

```
// the command
// Self_Test = Chr(27) + Chr(84) = ESC T
byte[] dBytes = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetBytes(Self_Test);

// wont work
new Java.IO.ObjectOutputStream(s.OutputStream).Write(dBytes);
// wont work
System.IO.Stream st = s.OutputStream;
if (st.CanWrite)
{
   st.Write(dBytes, 0, dBytes.Length);
   st.Flush();
}
// wonk work
s.OutputStream.Write(dBytes, 0, dBytes.Length);
s.OutputStream.Flush();
```

No error is raised. I'm running out of options here...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there any way to pair with a "debug" bluetooth device to see if the data is being sent at all? WIthout knowing what the error is and where it occurs, it's rather hard to fix...

Comment: No, there is not. But the same program is build in WM 6.x and working.
The main difference is that on WM I have a .dll to communicate and on Mono that wont work.
My problem is just to send the command and see something happen with the printer without using the .dll

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know this is a very old thread, but I wanted to post a reply so others will know the answer. I too searched hard with no luck.

```
s.OutputStream.BeginWrite(buffer, 0, buffer.Length,new AsyncCallback(delegate {}), State.Connected);
```

Thanks.